# PowerShell Invoke-RestMethod limited results

Tags: rest, powershell

I'm pretty novice to PowerShell and I've been trying to figure out why Invoke-RestMethod is only returning 10 results when I know there are more in the API I'm using; since I can't share the access token I'm using I tried and got the same results with Microsoft's example:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/feed/ |
    Format-Table -Property Title, pubDate
```

I feel like I'm missing a parameter or something simple but looking through MSDN and Googling did not help me find what I'm missing; I just want to make the API I'm using return all results instead of the first 10

Comment: [RSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS) is a type of web feed which allows users and applications to access **updates** to online content. There are no more than 10 news at  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/feed/. For more results, you need to parse HTML content of `https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/page/$X/` for each `$X in (1..116)` (here max page number = today 116, tomorrow maybe 116 or 117 etc.)

Comment: The code I'm actually writing is for the Canvas REST API [link](https://canvas.instructure.com/doc/api/) I just wanted to find another example since it would be a FERPA violation to post the working code with the access token and allow access to student data; I'm not sure what protocol it's actually using which is probably my first learning curve dealing with REST APIs. Thank you for that additional information though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the Canvas API I was actually using the answer was [pagination](https://canvas.instructure.com/doc/api/file.pagination.html), kudos to JosefZ who commented the correct answer!